# Laravel 8 - миграции и стартовые данные

Tags: laravel, миграция, seed

У меня проект на Laravel 8.
БД создавалась без миграций, теперь хочу их создать. По мере разработки **несколько таблиц оказались заполнены важной рабочей информацией**, собранной парсерами.
Если выполнить команду `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, то эти таблицы будут удалены с потерей информации.

**Я вижу несколько путей решения проблемы:**

1. Выполнять миграции командой `php artisan migrate:REfresh --seed` (тогда суффикс :fresh станет токсичным в этой команде *и будет приводить к потере данных*) и в миграциях прописать, чтобы таблицы с реальными данными не удалять и не трогать либо удалить миграции с этой таблицей.
2. Сделать сидер, куда выгружать важные таблицы в csv и импортировать их обратно (плохое решение) при выполнении миграций.
3. Вынесли эти таблицы в отдельную БД (что создает головную боль с несколькими соединениями и разными БД для разных запросов с соответствующими проблемами с отношениями и правами на БД).

Уважаемые коллеги, какие способы являются наилучшей практикой в данной ситуации?

Comment: Повторить структуру миграций, запустить на локалке, скоировать таблицу миграций на бой и не париться, ну и сидеры научить проверять что удалять, что обновлять а что вставлть

Comment: К сожалению это не защищает от потери информации при migrate:fresh и вынуждает разворачивать production через import / export базы

Comment: Зачем вам нужна именно эта команда `:fresh --seed` ? это решается довольно просто, обратите внимание на таблицу migrations. Туда можете написать название своей миграции и система будет считать что она уже выполнилась. После этого делайте каждый раз только `php artisan migrate`